# Left and right derivatives of piecewise function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am trying to calculate the left and right derivatives at each jump discontinuity of the given function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2,&-5\leq x < 1\\
2-x, &1 \le x < 3\\
1, & 3\leq x < 4\\
x-4, & 4 \leq x \leq 5 
\end{cases}$$

I am having trouble with the following cases: $f'(3^+), f'(4^-)$. I am unsure what to do with these since the function is just $1$. I know that both of the answers are $0 $ but I am not quite sure how to show this using the following formula

$$f'(x) = \lim _{h\rightarrow 0 }\frac{(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: $f (x)=1$ in this region, what's wrong with plugging this into your derivative formula?

Comment: @Kutz so would it become $\frac{3+h-1}{h}$? but this isn't $0$

Comment: I had assumed that was a typo in your post, but it seems you are not using the correct formula. The derivate of $f$ at $x$ is defined as $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f (x+h)-f (x)}{h}$

Comment: @Kutz yes sorry that was a typo, okay so say $f'(3+) = \lim _{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x+h)-1}{h }$ I am a little confused what $f(x+h)$ would be

Comment: Well, provided $0 <=h <1$, which is what we would be using for this limit, $f (3+h)=1$, right? For example, $f(3.3)=f(3.1)=f(3.9999)$. As you've correctly pointed out, tue function has a constant value of 1 on this interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
f'(3^+) &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(3+h)-f(3)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1-f(3)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{1-1}{h} \\
\end{align}

Similarly evaluate $$f'(4^-) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(4+h)-f(4)}{h} $$

Hint: Do not assume that the answer will be $0$.

Comment: so then wouldn't that just be $\lim _{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{1-1}{h } = \frac{0}{h} = 0?$

Comment: Yes for the first limit. btw, do not omit the $+$ sign in $0^+$.

Comment: that was my explanation for the second limit, and I didn't know if I should omit that but I will write it in

Comment: why would $f(3+h) = 1?$

Comment: what is the value of $f(3.1)$? what about $f(3.01)$? what about the $f(3.001)$? answer for second limit is wrong... what is $f(4)$?

Comment: so $f'(3^+) = 0 $ but $f'(4^-) \ne 0 $ I am not quite sure how to evaluate the second one

Comment: what is $f(4)$?

Comment: wouldn't you use the last part of the piecewise function and say $4-4 = 0?$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68264/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-user123).